# Multiple splash screen issue on iPhone5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, splash-screen, iphone-5

i have a simple class named Splashes that animate three images on startup.
It works well, but now on iPhone 5 I'm not able to automatically resize the view.

Here the code snippets:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  [...]
  if ( IS_IPHONE_5 ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_1-568h@2x.png"];
  else _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_1.png"];
  if ( IS_IPAD ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_1_ipad.png"];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(repeat) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  [...]
}
```

Repeat function

```
[...]
int i=0;
[...]
- (void)repeat
{
  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      if ( IS_IPHONE_5 ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_2-568h@2x.png"];
      else _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_2.png"];
      if ( IS_IPAD ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_2_ipad.png"];
      break;
    case 1:
      if ( IS_IPHONE_5 ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_3-568h@2x.png"];
      else _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_3.png"];
      if ( IS_IPAD ) _ImageSplash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_3_ipad.png"];
      break;
    default: [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

The images are correctly loaded, based on device, but the xib remain the same.
Don't want to autosize.

These are the settings of my XIB:
[image]
[image]

[image]

What's could be the problem?

All others XIB works well, I have a problem only with this.
iOS show me a black stripe only on the bottom of the view! Very strange...

Note: I can't use AUTOLAYOUTS because it's an 3.2+ app compatibile.

---

Edit: Added screenshot.
[image]

thanks.

Comment: can you share the screen i.e. what exactly happening on device? if possible?

Comment: Have you checked that 'Autoresize subviews' is checked in the XIB for the top level view?

Comment: Are you sure your `IS_IPHONE_5` macro is working correctly and that you aren't just loading the non-iphone 5 image? Have you set breakpoints to check which code is being executed?

Comment: Yes, image are loaded correctly, because are different. The ip5 image is with red spray...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CSmith's reply should have worked, but, anyways, may be this'd do the trick:

```
CGRect windowFrame=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0] bounds];
[_ImageSplash setFrame:windowFrame];
```

Put it under the iPhone5 check i.e. when device is iPhone5.

Comment: what's the contentMode for imageView? It'd be scaleToFill

Comment: Now, it's freaking out... Did you actually try the CSmith's suggestion, no offense, just making sure? Besides, if you've added the artifacts just now in the project then you need to clean compile the project and may need to delete the earlier build before running this one.

Comment: the autosizing window for imageView should look like that of your view.

Comment: I setted the right frame (ip5 or less) when initWithNibName. Seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Change the autosizing mask on your Image View to pin to TOP and BOTTOM, in addition to the current settings (i.e. pin to left, top, bottom, and allow flexible height).